# Editing remote MS Access Database with Devexpress

Tags: c#, database, devexpress

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to display data from a remote database and inserting,editing, and deleting data. The database that I am connecting to is a remote which I was successfully able to connect and view the information however when I insert the syntax to edit the data I get an error (see bottom of the post).
I am using Devexpress Scheduler Controller to view appointments as well edit them.
This is the entire code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    CarsDBDataSet dataSet;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        intSchedular();
    }

    private void intSchedular()
    {
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.AllDay = "AllDay";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Description = "Description";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.End = "EndTime";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Label = "Label";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Start = "StartTime";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Location = "Location";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.ReminderInfo = "RemindderInfo";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Subject = "Subject";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Status = "Status";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.Type = "EventType";
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.Mappings.RecurrenceInfo = "RecurrenceInfo";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        {
            ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data source= \\UNDERFOOT-PC\CalUnderFootDB\CarsDB.mdb"
        };

        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand createCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from CarScheduling", con);
        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(createCommand);
        CarsDBDataSet dataSet = new CarsDBDataSet();

        // Bind the scheduler storage to appointment data.  
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentStorage.DataSource = dataSet.CarScheduling;

        // Load data into the 'CarsDBDataSet.CarScheduling' table.   
        adapter.Fill(dataSet.CarScheduling);
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentsInserted +=
             new PersistentObjectsEventHandler(Storage_AppointmentsModified);
        schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentsChanged +=
            new PersistentObjectsEventHandler(Storage_AppointmentsModified);
       schudlerControl1.Storage.AppointmentsDeleted +=
            new PersistentObjectsEventHandler(Storage_AppointmentsModified);

       adapter.Adapter.RowUpdated +=
           new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(adapter_RowUpdated);
    }


    void Storage_AppointmentsModified(object sender, PersistentObjectsEventArgs e)
    {

        adapter.Adapter.Update(dataSet);
        this.dataSet.AcceptChanges();
    }

    private void adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue && e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
        {
            int id = 0;
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", adapter.Connection))
            {
                id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            e.Row["ID"] = id;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is from the word adapter from "void Storage_AppointmentsModified" saying "the name 'adapter' does not exist in the current context". I know I have to define adapter but how? I am new to C# so I am not "fluent" with writing C# syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the adapter variable inside the `intSchedular` method. But this variable is local to that method and cannot be used outside of it (It will be destroyed when you exit from `intSchedular`)

To be able to use the variable in `Storage_AppointmentsModified`, you need to define it at the global class scope like you already do with the `CarsDBDataSet`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    CarsDBDataSet dataSet;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    .....

private void intSchedular()
{
    .....
    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(createCommand);
    .....
}    

void Storage_AppointmentsModified(object sender, PersistentObjectsEventArgs e)
{
    this.adapter.Update(dataSet);
    this.dataSet.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Another thing to fix in your code is the Handling of the connection. A Connection should be used following a precise pattern. Create, Open, Use, Close and Destroy. You should be using the using statement in your intSchedular to be sure of the destruction of  the connection

```
private void intSchedular()
{
    // CREATE 
    using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(... con string here....))
    using(OleDbCommand createCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from CarScheduling", con))
    {
         // OPEN
         con.Open();
         // NO USING HERE BECAUSE WE WANT THE ADAPTER OUTSIDE OF THIS METHOD
         adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(createCommand);
         // USE
         ....
         adapter.Fill(dataSet.CarScheduling);
         ....
    } // CLOSE + DISPOSE
}
```

The same thing should be done in the `adapter_RowUpdated`

```
private void adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue && e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        int id = 0;
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection( .... con string here ....))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        e.Row["ID"] = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: but at the "Storage_AppointmentsModified" when you enter the code "this.adapter.Update(dataSet)" you deleted Adapter in "private void intSchedular()".

Comment: In intSchedular I have removed the declaration of adapter because it is already declared at the global level. Thus a new declaration inside intSchedular will obfuscate the external global one. Instead I want the global one to be initialized by the `new OleDbDataAdapter(...)`

Comment: oh I see now ok! I understand but this will cause me another problem. In the  `private void adapter_RowUpdated` (the last void) I get another error on the word `Connection` saying **Error 1 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and no extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users...** this line of code I am talking about `using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", adapter.Connection))`

Comment: You could grab the connection from `adapter.SelectCommand.Connection`. But the best method is to recreate the connection. Also be aware that a connection should be closed and disposed. I will add something in the answer about that

Comment: 1 more question and I think I got! (THANK YOU BTW). In the `void Storage_AppointmentsModified(object sender, PersistentObjectsEventArgs e)` you changed `this.adapter.Adapter.Update(dataSet);` to `this.adapter.Update(dataSet);` when I run the program and I add an appointment the debuger hightlights this code `this.adapter.Update(dataSet);` and tells me **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** AGAIN! THANK YOU SIR FOR TEACHING ME!

Comment: Sorry, my fail, if you have followed the last example, the adapter is redeclared inside the using statement and thus is not the global one. In this case you need to remove the using around the initialization of the adapter. I will fix the answer now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38301/discussion-between-imak-and-steve)